# JMeter: Best way to call/use 1000 test users in batch sequence from csv for a given time and then to switch to next batch 1000 out of 5k total users

Tags: csv, jmeter

**Problem Statement**: I am trying to replicate realistic sceanrio mentioned by my dev team. *There are 5000 Test Users stored in testusers.CSV in sequence. And jmeter should call/use them in batches of 1000 test users to call HTTP purchase req. So we start with 1000 and cycle through them around five minute, then load the next 1000 and cycle through them for next 5 min and then pick next set and so on. So 5 batches and some hours to cycle through before going back to the start. Basically every five minute only 1000 users should be used. And each user can make multiple calls from a sequence but I need to make sure that there are no concurrent calls from the same user.*

> Test setup looks like

```
TestPlan
CSVDataSetConfigForTestUsers
ThreadGroup
Throughput Controller_1
HTTP Purchase_Req1
Throughput Controller_2
HTTP Purchase_Req2
```

> There is a way I can think of is to use 1000 threads which will pick first 1000 users and so on. But this logic will fail when we have batch of 8000 or 10,000 users. Another way is to divide file of 5k users to 1k and create 5 csv files like this which can be supplied to HTTP req stored in 5 separate controllers. But again not sure how this will work exactly and to feasible for large number of test users.
> *Is there any way to achieve this in more practical way?*

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way of implementing your scenario is switching to [__groovy() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) to read the data from the file, i.e.

```
${__groovy(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines().get(ctx.getThreadNum()),)}
```

this way 1st thread will read 1st line, 2nd thread 2nd line, etc.

With regards to kicking off users you can consider using [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) configured like:

[image]

Comment: @stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t Thanks for the answer.I placed groovy code CSV data set config 'filename' section.But this is throwing an error 2022-03-18 ```18:22:52,556 INFO o.a.j.s.FileServer: Stored: path:\to\local\file\Folder1/20TestU.csv 2022-03-18 18:22:52,554 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19,Size: 1 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:162) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]``` can you help me with this error?

Comment: @stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t For quick test, I reduced setup to 20users instead of 5000 and configured UTG as displayed in image. (Instead of 5000 now 5 threads for 60sec i.e 4 iteration with total execution time of 4min. But this setup is not kicking out the users after execution. As I see same users are getting used in request after completion of 20users. Is there something I am doing wrong? Could you please help with this and above query? Cheers. Thanks in advance